# Retrieving YouTube Live Categories

Tags: youtube-api

I am looking for a way to retrieve categories from YouTube Live.

For example retrieve all channels from "Gaming" http://www.youtube.com/live/gaming

Answer (score 1):

If you do a guideCategories list "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories/list" , you will see "gaming has category id = 'GCR2FtaW5n'

So when you do a channel list

"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2C+snippet%2C+contentDetails%2C+statistics%2C+topicDetails&categoryId=GCR2FtaW5n&key={YOUR_API_KEY}"

you will get all channels related to "Gaming". To find out live shows, you can check do playlist list then iterate through videos and find videos with contentDetails.duration=0

"https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration"